# Eclipse (Kepler) How do I upgrade subversive SVN Connector

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, subversive

In our developer team we have recently switched to latest version of svn (1.9.3) from the old 1.7.x series.

After the local working copy upgrade we remembered that in eclipse we used  subversive SVN connector for 1.7 which is not compatible with newer repo format.

How can we upgrade the connector without trashing eclipse completely? Of course without reinstalling everiting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case that is needed by someone else: You can install other connectors from polarion software site:

http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/3.0/update-site/

Then when you upgrade the working copy eclipse politely ask which connector you want to use if the current one is incompatible with the local repository.